# Progress indicator is not rendering in LWC

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-progressindicator

I have the following lwc:

```
<template if:true={dependentPickListOptions}>
                <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={gdependentvalue} type="path" variant="base">
                        <template for:each={dependentPickListOptions} for:item="f">
                            <lightning-progress-step label={f.label} value={f.value} key={f.value}></lightning-progress-step>
                        </template>
                    </lightning-progress-indicator>
                </div>
        </template>
```

js:

```
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$gnumber", fields: "$extfields", modes: ["View"] })
        globalRecord({ error, data }) {
            console.log("globalRecord data: ", JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("globalRecord error: ", JSON.stringify(error));
            if (data) {
                if (data.fields) {
                    this.gcontrollervalue = data.fields.Status__c.value;
                    this.gdependentvalue = data.fields.SubStatus_c__c.value;
                }
            }
            if (error) {
                console.log(error + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }

  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId", fieldApiName: "$fieldDependentPicklistValues" })
        getGDependentPL({ error, data }) {
        
            if (data) {
                this.dependencyMap = data;
        
                this.dependentPickListOptions = this.dependencyMap[this.gcontrollervalue];
                console.log("gcontrollervalue: ", this.gcontrollervalue);

            } else if (error) {
                console.log("error: ", JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }
```

I get `gcontrollervalue` from another wire and most of the time when I log it is empty. I know that when wire provisions results from server `gcontrollervalue` will be populated, but how can I use the provisioned value in the other wire?

Comment: Did that answer make sense? Have you had a go? Another thing: maybe consider changing this: `if:true={dependentPickListOptions}` to look at an actual boolean based on these options.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the dependent wire fire by using a **Compound Reactive Parameter** to the wire definition. A compound reactive parameter is really just your regular variable + some other value. A change in either will trigger the getter.

Your `wire` will look the same:

```
  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId", fieldApiName: "$fieldDependentPicklistValues" })
```

Here's the compound getter:

```
  //declare a private var
  _recordTypeId;

  //always use this to reference the var
  get recordTypeId(){
    if (!this.gcontrollervalue){
      return null;
    }
    //note this is now a private variable.
    return this._recordTypeId
   }
```

When you change `_recordTypeId` and `gcontrollervalue` the getter will fire which will in turn tell the `wire` method to fire.